# I did 3d model at work, did save .blend file to cloud... textures missing at home

Tags: texturing

So my problem: I did 3d model at work, did save .blend file to cloud... textures missing when im loading this .blend file at home. I have same texture files at home, but diffrent folder structure. How can i modify .blend file to search those textures (jpg) on hard drive? Now my model is simple purple coloured without textures (at home).

Answer (score 3):

Go to File menu / External Datas / Find missing files, then select the right folder on your computer.

A way to avoid this is to check "Automatically pack into .blend" (in File / External Data) before saving ; this will include every texture into the blend file.

Another (better?) way is to use Relative Path data and keep the same folder structure. I usually don't "move" a blend alone, but his entire folder, including his textures/assets/etc subfolders.

Comment: Thank you very much. This did the trick. Good advices!